# In WiX can Windows Service re-start delays be set individually?

Tags: wix, wix3.6

The SERVICE_FAILURE_ACTIONS struct contains multiple SC_ACTIONs (normally 3). Each contains a re-start delay.

However in WiX the util:ServiceConfig contains a single RestartServiceDelayInSeconds which sets the value for all 3.

e.g.

```
  <util:ServiceConfig FirstFailureActionType="restart"
                      SecondFailureActionType="restart"
                      ThirdFailureActionType="restart"
                      ResetPeriodInDays="1"
                      RestartServiceDelayInSeconds="1" />
```

Is there a way to give 3 different values for the delay for the 3 failure actions?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not possible. The description of the `RestartServiceDelayInSeconds` states:

> If **any of the three** *ActionType attributes is "restart", this specifies the number of seconds to wait before doing so.